# The specified task executable "postsharp.4.0-x86.exe" could not be run. The filename or extension is too long

Tags: postsharp

PostSharp build step fails with

> The specified task executable "postsharp.4.0-x86.exe" could not be
>   run. The filename or extension is too long

when run on build machine or locally with `PostSharpHost=Native`.

The cause looks to be the large number of references passed to postsharp.4.0-x86.exe via `/P:ResolvedReferences` parameter.

It works fine locally when using default `PostSharpHost=PipeServer`. However, PipeServer value is being ignored on build machine when build is run in non-interactive mode.

What are the options to resolve this issue? Is is possible to force using PipeServer on the build machine in non-interactive mode?

Here is a fragment from build log causing the issue:

```
C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\3.1.73\bin.Release\postsharp.4.0-x86.exe obj\Release\Before-PostSharp\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll /X:default /NoLogo /L:44054-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx /P:Output=C:\Dev\Xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\obj\Release\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll /P:ReferenceDirectory=C:\Dev\Xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\Xxx.Xxxxx.XxxxXxxxx /P:Configuration=Release /P:Platform=AnyCPU "/P:SearchPath=..\bin\|obj\Release\|C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\|C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\ " /P:IntermediateDirectory=obj\Release\PostSharp /P:CleanIntermediate=False /P:MSBuildProjectFullPath=C:\Dev\Xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\Xxx.Xxxxx.XxxxXxxxx.csproj /P:SignAssembly=False /P:PrivateKeyLocation= /P:PrivateKeyContainer= /P:DelaySign= "/P:ResolvedReferences=C:\Dev\Xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxxxxm\lib\AWSSDK.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\BitSyntax\lib\net45\BitSyntax.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\BitSyntax\lib\net45\BitSyntaxCs.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxxxxm\lib\Castle.Core.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxxxxm\lib\Castle.Windsor.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\XxxxxxCxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxx.xxxxxxxs.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\XxxxxxCxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxs.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\XxxxxxCxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\XxxxxxCxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxs.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxxxxm\lib\FileHelpers.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\FSharp.Core\lib\net40\FSharp.Core.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\FSharp.Data\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\FsPickler.CSharp\lib\net45\FsPickler.CSharp.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\FsPickler\lib\net45\FsPickler.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\FsPickler.Json\lib\net45\FsPickler.Json.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\FsUnit\Lib\Net40\FsUnit.NUnit.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxg\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxg\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxi\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxi\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\XxxxxxCxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxg\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxg\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxt\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxt\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxn\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxn\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxl\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxl\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxt\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxt\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxt\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxt\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxp\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxp\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxn\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxn\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxn\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxn\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxr\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxr\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxe\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxl\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxl\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxl\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxr\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxr\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.Genesis.Roaring20s\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.Genesis.Roaring20s\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxk\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxk\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxa\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxy\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxn\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxn\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxl\lib\net40\Xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxxxxm\lib\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\bin\Release\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxs\bin\Release\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxl\bin\Release\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-xx\packages\Xxx.xxxxx\lib\net40\Xxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dll|C:\Dev\xxxxx\xxx-xxxxx-
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [issue has been fixed](http://support.sharpcrafters.com/discussions/problems/2923-the-specified-task-executable-postsharp40-x86exe-could-not-be-run-the-filename-or-extension-is-too-long) in PostSharp 4.2.14. Please update to the latest version.